Multiple Conditional Formats Repeated Across Tabs
I have a google form that has a few different inputs that goes to a google sheet. One of the inputs is the name of the person filling out the form. I have created a tab for each user (about 170) and set it up so that each time there's an entry then a query function sorts the data into the respective tab. I've tried  using a macro to write a script to highlight data from the past seven days in one color and the past six weeks in another color. The second function recreates the formatting for each tab but it takes too long and I can only get about 1/4 of the way within whatever time limit is enforced by appscript. Am I missing something or is there an easier way to do this so I don't have to manually do this for all 170 tabs?
function Condition_Tabs() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  var conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2')])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#46bdc6')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2:H1000')])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#46bdc6')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2:H1000')])
  .whenDateEqualTo(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.TODAY)
  .setBackground('#46bdc6')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2:H1000')])
  .whenDateEqualTo(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.PAST_WEEK)
  .setBackground('#46bdc6')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.push(SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2')])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#fbbc04')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2:H1000')])
  .whenCellNotEmpty()
  .setBackground('#fbbc04')
  .build());
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D11').activate();
  conditionalFormatRules = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getConditionalFormatRules();
  conditionalFormatRules.splice(conditionalFormatRules.length - 1, 1, SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .setRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('A2:H1000')])
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=if(WEEKNUM((INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))=WEEKNUM((TODAY()-36), 1), 1,0)=1')
  .setBackground('#fbbc04')
  .build( ));
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
}

function Condition_allTabs(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();

  allSheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    if(sheet.getSheetName() !== "Form Responses 1") {
      sheet.activate();
      Condition_Tabs()

    }
  })
}


Have you looked into using the Advanced Sheets Services to add the conditional formatting rules instead? You could queue the formatting rules into JSON and apply them to the workbook using batchUpdate.
